# .animate() not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

can't make my background image' position animate

```
$(function() {
$('#nav1').bind('click',function(event){
        $('ul.nav').stop().animate({backgroundPosition: 'right top'}, 1000); 
});
    $(function() {
    $('#nav2').bind('click',function(event){
            $('ul.nav').stop().animate({backgroundPosition: 'right 38px'}, 1000); 
});
    $(function() {
    $('#nav3').bind('click',function(event){
            $('ul.nav').stop().animate({backgroundPosition: 'right 76px'}, 1000); 
});
    $(function() {
    $('#nav4').bind('click',function(event){
            $('ul.nav').stop().animate({backgroundPosition: 'right 114px'}, 1000); 
});
```

and html code is

```
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="#what"  id="nav1">what</a></li>
<li><a href="#who" id="nav2">who</a></li>
<li><a href="#portfolio" id="nav3">portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact" id="nav4">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

i've tried not using pixels like this {backgroundPosition: '0 38'} but it still not animating it just changed the position

and there is another issue. i repeat the jquery code for each item in the menu , could you plz make it in one function ,the position shifts 38px vertically for each item.
thanks,

Comment: @attack thanks the plugin works like charm but not the function
the position stays still i think it needs some math functions !

Comment: Whoops, my bad! Is the updated function what you need?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to use valid numbers to get it to work, I don't think it can calculate the text values right,left, center etc

Comment: @attack nice job , i just replaced (this) whith 'ul.nav' and worked perfectly .
great thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not you.

jQuery doesn't natively support background position animations. However, there is a wonderful plugin:
http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/

And here's the function you asked for:

```
$(function() {
    $('ul.nav a').each(function(i, elem) {
        $(elem).bind('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var offset = i * 38;
            $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition: '0 ' + offset + 'px'}, 1000); 
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [CSS3 transitions](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/) and [jQuery.CSS()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to trigger the transition.

Answer (score 0):

'right 38px' is not valid value of `background-position`. Fix it and it should work.